# C# MVC property name to HTML id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I know that I could do this manually, but is there a built in function to convert a C# MVC Razor property name to the value that Razor will use as the HTML id?

**To expand on this question:**

I am trying to access the HTML element using JavaScript in a partial view. (The partial view means that I do not have access to the parameter name directly.)

**The following two partial solutions double up the ID, giving you ParameterName_ParameterName:**

```
string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
@Html.Id(name)
@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(name)
```

**The solution I'm going with at the moment:**

```
Regex.Replace(name, @"[\.\[\]]", "_");
```

I guess you could add parentheses.

Comment: You mean [@Html.IdFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709(v=vs.108).aspx)?

Comment: Are you using Razor or not?

Comment: @wegginho Using Razor, yes.

Comment: @Zabavsky Yes, but I need to convert the property name as a string. @Html.Id(PropertyName) does it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can use either `@Html.IdFor(m => m.PropertyName)` or `@Html.Id("PropertyName")`. The last one is error prone though.

Comment: @Zabavsky I spoke too soon, it's giving me double, like `PropertyName_PropertyName`.

Comment: It is a correct Id. The helper adds `HtmlFieldPrefix` to it which is the parent property name.

Comment: There's also `TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId`

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments:

IMHO you should not be using your model in that fashion. If you need access to children objects, create a new model and bind to it that exposes that directly. Then in your controller piece back together your original model as needed. In the case of a Registration Form, if its highly complex, try breaking it up in to smaller pieces (seperate views), otherwise use a flat model that combines all the fields like Username, Password, etc then assign values to the appropriate objects.

Remember that the least amount of complexity is the better solution, as it improves maintainability.

Comment: My issue is that within a partial view I am trying to access the HTML element using JavaScript.

Comment: If your model is correct then you would be accessing it using simply `$("#Username")` or `document.getElementById("Username")`

Comment: As far as I know I can't use the same partial view + model multiple times on the same page because they will all end up with the same id/name, ie, if I don't use `Parent[x].Child` then the inputs will all have the same id/name `Child`. If I'm wrong about that I'd love to hear a solution.

Comment: If you could provide more information as to what you're attempting to do, then I could help further in getting you the right solution.

Comment: Say I have a model with a list (of variable length) of strings that I want to have HTML text input boxes for. How do I get the data back without using `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Parameter[x])`? What about if it's a list of objects with a string parameter, how do I get the data back without using `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Parent[x].Child)`? In either of those cases if I use a partial view with a model of string the id/name of each input will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a moldel

something like this

```
 public class AnnonymousModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z\n\r\0-9_ ]+$")]
        public String RegisterUsername {get; set;}
   }
```

and then use it in mvc view page

For Razor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterUsername, new { @class = "inp-form", @placeholder = "User name" })
```

For asp

```
<%Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterUsername, new { @class = "inp-form", @placeholder = "User name" })%>
```

the in the Html renderd is like this

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="User name" name="RegisterUsername" 
id="RegisterUsername" data-val-required="The User name field is required." data-val-regex-

pattern="^[A-Za-z\n\r\0-9_ ]+$" data-val-regex="The field User name must match the regular 

expression '^[A-Za-z\n\r\0-9_ ]+$'." data-val-length-min="3" data-val-length-max="20" 

data-val-length="The User name must be at least 3 characters long." data-val="true" 

class="inp-form">
```

So the `Id` is `automatically generated` as the `property name specified`.

Comment: But if the property name includes special characters such as periods, square brackets, etc, they get converted to underscores, eg, `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register[0].Username, new { @class = "inp-form", @placeholder = "User name" })`